# 'RtcDateTime' does not name a type

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, c, rtc, ds3231-alarms

I've tested a code that compiles successfully.

But after i merged it to another code, here it shown an error says RtcDateTime doesn't name a type.

Used library : https://github.com/Makuna/Rtc

[image]

Some notes : 
- RtcDateTime instances are being used in setup() and loop() without a problem.
- RtcDS3231 header file is included (which includes RtcDateTime.h inside it).
- Tried to include RtcDateTime.h in my sketch, doesn't work !

Code : (Contains combination of 3 devices : RTC , I2C Ultrasonic and HX711 loadcell)

```
/*
Below, I define the SCL and SDA pins by their ATMEGA pins I have included links to common mappings below.
    UNO:  http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168
    NANO: (matches UNO but has fewer pins)
    MEGA 2560: http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560
The current data matches the setup for the Arduino Uno -- they may need to be changed if the hardware changes.
You can also switch the I2C interface
to any of the tristate pins that you want (not just the SDA or SCL pins).
*/
#define SCL_PIN D2              //Default SDA is Pin5 PORTC for the UNO -- you can set this to any tristate pin
#define SDA_PIN D1              //Default SCL is Pin4 PORTC for the UNO -- you can set this to any tristate pin
#define I2C_TIMEOUT 100        //Define a timeout of 100 ms -- do not wait for clock stretching longer than this time


#include "HX711.h"  //You must have this library in your arduino library folder

#define DOUT  D1
#define CLK  D2

HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);
float calibration_factor = -10060; //-106600 worked for my 40Kg max scale setup 

/*
I have included a couple of extra useful settings for easy reference.
//#define I2C_CPUFREQ (F_CPU/8)//Useful if you plan on doing any clock switching
#define I2C_FASTMODE 1         //Run in fast mode (400 kHz)
#define I2C_SLOWMODE 1         //If you do not define the mode it will run at 100kHz with this define set to 1 it will run at 25kHz
*/
#include <SlowSoftI2CMaster.h>     //You will need to install this library
// create new instance with A4 as SDA, A5 as SCL and enable internal pullups
SlowSoftI2CMaster si = SlowSoftI2CMaster(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);



/*
 *  RTC Code starts here 
 */

#include <Wire.h> // must be included here so that Arduino library object file references work
#include <RtcDS3231.h>
RtcDS3231<TwoWire> Rtc(Wire);
/*
 *  RTC Headers Ending
 */


void setup(){
  // Initialize both the serial and I2C bus
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Press T to tare");
  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor);  //Calibration Factor obtained from first sketch
  scale.tare();             //Reset the scale to 0  

if (!si.i2c_init()) // initialize I2C module
        Serial.println("I2C init failed");



    /*
     *  RTC Setup :
     */
     Rtc.Begin(SDA_PIN,SCL_PIN);

    RtcDateTime compiled = RtcDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);
    printDateTime(compiled);
    Serial.println();

    if (!Rtc.IsDateTimeValid()) 
    {
        // Common Cuases:
        //    1) first time you ran and the device wasn't running yet
        //    2) the battery on the device is low or even missing

        Serial.println("RTC lost confidence in the DateTime!");

        // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
        // it will also reset the valid flag internally unless the Rtc device is
        // having an issue

        Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);
    }

    if (!Rtc.GetIsRunning())
    {
        Serial.println("RTC was not actively running, starting now");
        Rtc.SetIsRunning(true);
    }

    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
    if (now < compiled) 
    {
        Serial.println("RTC is older than compile time!  (Updating DateTime)");
        Rtc.SetDateTime(compiled);
    }
    else if (now > compiled) 
    {
        Serial.println("RTC is newer than compile time. (this is expected)");
    }
    else if (now == compiled) 
    {
        Serial.println("RTC is the same as compile time! (not expected but all is fine)");
    }

    // never assume the Rtc was last configured by you, so
    // just clear them to your needed state
    Rtc.Enable32kHzPin(false);
    Rtc.SetSquareWavePin(DS3231SquareWavePin_ModeNone); 

    /*
     *  RTC Setup Ending
     */
}
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

void loop()
{
  if (!si.i2c_init()) // initialize I2C module
        Serial.println("I2C init failed");
  // (OPTIONAL) Read a sensor at the default address
  read_the_sensor_example();

  scale.begin(SDA_PIN,SCL_PIN);
  Serial.print("Weight: ");
  Serial.print(scale.get_units(), 5);  //Up to 3 decimal points
  Serial.println(" kg"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you follow lbs

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    char temp = Serial.read();
    if(temp == 't' || temp == 'T')
      scale.tare();  //Reset the scale to zero      
  }

  /*
   *  RTC Loop Start
   */
  if (!Rtc.IsDateTimeValid()) 
    {
        // Common Cuases:
        //    1) the battery on the device is low or even missing and the power line was disconnected
        Serial.println("RTC lost confidence in the DateTime!");
    }

    RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();


    Serial.println();
    // String date = dateS(now);
    // String time = timeS(now);



  RtcTemperature temp = Rtc.GetTemperature();
  temp.Print(Serial);
  // you may also get the temperature as a float and print it
    // Serial.print(temp.AsFloatDegC());
    Serial.println("C");

  /*
   *    RTC loop Ending
   */
}

void printDateTime(const RtcDateTime& dt)
{
    char datestring[20];

    snprintf_P(datestring, 
            countof(datestring),
            PSTR("%02u/%02u/%04u %02u:%02u:%02u"),
            dt.Month(),
            dt.Day(),
            dt.Year(),
            dt.Hour(),
            dt.Minute(),
            dt.Second() );
    Serial.print(datestring);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: Start a range reading on the sensor //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Uses the I2C library to start a sensor at the given address
//Collects and reports an error bit where: 1 = there was an error or 0 = there was no error.
//INPUTS: byte bit8address = the address of the sensor that we want to command a range reading
//OUPUTS: bit  errorlevel = reports if the function was successful in taking a range reading: 1 = the function
//  had an error, 0 = the function was successful
boolean start_sensor(byte bit8address){
  boolean errorlevel = 0;
  bit8address = bit8address & B11111110;               //Do a bitwise 'and' operation to force the last bit to be zero -- we are writing to the address.
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_start(bit8address) | errorlevel;   //Run i2c_start(address) while doing so, collect any errors where 1 = there was an error.
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_write(81) | errorlevel;            //Send the 'take range reading' command. (notice how the library has error = 0 so I had to use "!" (not) to invert the error)
  si.i2c_stop();
  return errorlevel;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: Read the range from the sensor at the specified address //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Uses the I2C library to read a sensor at the given address
//Collects errors and reports an invalid range of "0" if there was a problem.
//INPUTS: byte  bit8address = the address of the sensor to read from
//OUPUTS: int   range = the distance in cm that the sensor reported; if "0" there was a communication error
int read_sensor(byte bit8address){
  boolean errorlevel = 0;
  int range = 0;
  byte range_highbyte = 0;
  byte range_lowbyte = 0;
  bit8address = bit8address | B00000001;  //Do a bitwise 'or' operation to force the last bit to be 'one' -- we are reading from the address.
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_start(bit8address) | errorlevel;
  range_highbyte = si.i2c_read(0);           //Read a byte and send an ACK (acknowledge)
  range_lowbyte  = si.i2c_read(1);           //Read a byte and send a NACK to terminate the transmission
  si.i2c_stop();
  range = (range_highbyte * 256) + range_lowbyte;  //compile the range integer from the two bytes received.
  if(errorlevel){
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    return range;
  }
}



/////////////////////////////////////////
// Function: Change the sensor address //
/////////////////////////////////////////
//Uses the I2C library to change the address of a sensor at a given address
//Collects and reports an error bit where: 1 = there was an error or 0 = there was no error.
//INPUTS: byte oldaddress = the current address of the sensor that we want to change
//INPUTS: byte newddress  = the address that we want to change the sensor to
//OUPUTS: bit  errorlevel = reports if the function was successful in changing the address: 1 = the function had an
//      error, 0 = the function was successful
boolean change_address(byte oldaddress,byte newaddress){
  //note that the new address will only work as an even number (odd numbers will round down)
  boolean errorlevel = 0;
  oldaddress = oldaddress & B11111110;  //Do a bitwise 'and' operation to force the last bit to be zero -- we are writing to the address.
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_start(oldaddress) | errorlevel; //Start communication at the new address and track error codes
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_write(170) | errorlevel;        //Send the unlock code and track the error codes
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_write(165) | errorlevel;        //Send the unlock code and track the error codes
  errorlevel = !si.i2c_write(newaddress) | errorlevel; //Send the new address
//  si.i2c_stop();
  return errorlevel;
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code Example: Read the sensor at the default address //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void read_the_sensor_example(){
  boolean error = 0;  //Create a bit to check for catch errors as needed.
  int range;

  //Take a range reading at the default address of 224
  error = start_sensor(224);    //Start the sensor and collect any error codes.
  if (!error){                  //If you had an error starting the sensor there is little point in reading it as you will get old data.
    delay(100);
    range = read_sensor(224);   //reading the sensor will return an integer value -- if this value is 0 there was an error
    Serial.print("R:");Serial.println(range);
  }
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code Example: Poll all possible addresses to find a sensor //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void address_polling_example(){
  boolean error = 0;  //Create a bit to check for catch errors as needed.
  int range = 0;
  Serial.println("Polling addresses...");

  //Walk through all possible addresses and check for a device that can receive the range command and will
  //    return two bytes.
  for (byte i=2; i!=0; i+=2){   //start at 2 and count up by 2 until wrapping to 0. Checks all addresses (2-254) except 0 (which cannot be used by a device)
    error = 0;
    error = start_sensor(i);    //Start the sensor and collect any error codes.
    if (!error){                //If you had an error starting the sensor there is little point in reading it.
      delay(100);
      range = read_sensor(i);   //reading the sensor will return an integer value -- if this value is 0 there was an error
      Serial.println(i);
      if (range != 0){
        Serial.print("Device found at:");Serial.print(i);Serial.print(" Reported value of:");Serial.println(range);
      }  
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Couldn't start:");Serial.println(i);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Address polling complete.");
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code Example: Change the default address //
//////////////////////////////////////////////
void default_address_change_example(){
  boolean error = 0;  //Create a bit to check for catch errors as needed.
  int range;

  Serial.println("Take a reading at the default address");

  //Take a range reading at the default address of 224
  error = start_sensor(224);    //Start the sensor and collect any error codes.
  if (!error){                  //If you had an error starting the sensor there is little point in reading it.
    delay(100);
    range = read_sensor(224);   //reading the sensor will return an integer value -- if this value is 0 there was an error
    Serial.print("R:");Serial.println(range);
  }

   Serial.println("Change the sensor at the default address to 222");
  //Change the address from 224 to 222
  error = 0;
  error = change_address(224,222);  //Change the address -- I don't do anything with the error handler at this point but you can if you want.
  delay(200);    //Wait 125ms for the sensor to save the new address and reset

   Serial.println("Take a reading at the new address");

  //Take a range reading at the new address of 222
  error = 0;
  error = start_sensor(222);     //Same as above but at the new address
  if (!error){
    delay(100);
    range = read_sensor(222);
    Serial.print("N:");Serial.println(range);
  }  

   Serial.println("Change the sensor back to the default address");  

  //Change the address from 222 to 224
  error = 0;
  error = change_address(222,224);
  delay(200);    //Wait 125ms for the sensor to save the new address and reset

}
```

So i have no idea why this happens .

Any help ?

Comment: well, I'VE FOUND THE ERROR! But wtf is this error !? after trimming code out many times finding what addition caused the error. it was line 21 `float calibration_factor = -10060; ` switching it on/off is the edge of the error appearing !

Comment: Believe or don't believe ! the comment causes the error [facepalm]

Comment: What version of the IDE are you using? I believe the problem is with the location of the auto generated function prototypes.

Comment: It's 1.8.7 - But it's so weird a comment can cause such a thing !

Comment: It's not the comment. It's the face that the float is before the include, and that float is where the IDE codes to place the prototypes. Move the include for the rtc to before that float.

Comment: move all includes to the top of the file. you make it hard for Arduino builder ino-to-cpp conversion with your style

Comment: @Majenko  Thanks for the solution! Now it compiles without errors :) . But the weird thing that removing the comment was resolving the error too! xD

Comment: @Majenko Is it terrible if i split my sketch into more than a helper .h file within sketch directory, then include them all in my .ino file?

Comment: Weird things happen with the Arduino IDE's prototypes if you're not careful. It's one of the first things I tackled in UECIDE, which always places the prototypes immediately before the first actual function in the code.

Comment: It is better to split your code into multiple INO files. The IDE then combines them for you - no need to include them manually.

Comment: So, INO not h files ? there could be some interactions between them.

Comment: The INO files are only separate to you. To the code it's just one single INO file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you.  I see that there could be 1 .ino file between some .h files at sketch folder, where these are included into .ino file as a header. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Majenko I've just read a thread in arduino forums, It's now more clear to me. I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Majenko Hi mister, I've tried to split my code into multi INO files. But the error message returns to appear. I've checked in every INO file : library includes first, then comes defines, then comes global instances and variables.

Comment: Make sure that the includes only come at the start of the "main" .INO file - the one that is the name of the sketch.

Comment: Thank you very much @Majenko, It works now without any problem. I had before split the includes into files too. Now fixed that and it compiles (y)

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same problem,  place the printDateTime function on the first page or the page where the headers and declaration's available

below function

```
#define countof(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
void printDateTime(const RtcDateTime& dt)
{
    char datestring[20];

    snprintf_P(datestring, 
            countof(datestring),
            PSTR("%02u/%02u/%04u %02u:%02u:%02u"),
            dt.Month(),
            dt.Day(),
            dt.Year(),
            dt.Hour(),
            dt.Minute(),
            dt.Second() );
    Serial.print(datestring);
}
```